# Determine Render Mechanism NextJS 13 Will Use with Child Client Component in a Server Component

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

Assuming the next pseudo page layout:

```js
// This is a server component
<div>
        <Header/> // This is a server component
        <Navbar/> // This is a client component
        <Footer/> // This is a server component
</div>
```

"Navbar", for this case, has a login-button, or, if the user is logged in - The user's name and his avatar image.

Since Navbar needs state from the client - Can the page be rendered in SSR mechanism, or the whole page needs to be compiled on the client? (CSR).

If SSR is available here, will I be able to cache some of the page somehow and use ISR? And only use CSR for my specific client component?

Thanks!

Comment: In Next.js 13, your setup can be handled with a mix of Server Components and Client Components. When using a mixture of server and client components, the entire page cannot be fully cached as a static page. Therefore, you won't be able to leverage ISR.